# send data using flutter-inappwebview to web page

Tags: php, postdata, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using inappwebview package, which opens a web page. I want to receive some data from my Flutter app to my web page (php/html) or there's may be some better option? Basically the user select a product in the app and then the inappwebview package will open this web page to show some specific products). 
I have found that inappwebview **postData**: "Loads the given [url] with [postData] using POST method into this WebView" and what I have tried is;

```html
    controller.postUrl(
    url: "web link",
    postData: utf8.encode(data)
    );
```

And in web page (php) I don't know how this data receives, I tried to write it like this;

```html
$data =utf8_decode($_POST['postData']);
```

Which is not correct i guess. Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `postData` argument represents the Body of the HTTP POST request.

A simple example using the latest version `5.0.5+3` of the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/versions/5.0.5+3) plugin is:

```dart
var postData = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode("firstname=Foo&lastname=Bar"));
controller.postUrl(url: Uri.parse("https://example.com/my-post-endpoint"), postData: postData);
```

where the `postData` is the Body of the request in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

So, in your PHP server, you can access the `firstname` and `lastname` values as you normally would do, that is `$_POST['firstname']` and `$_POST['lastname']`.